# Vue - show line with error in Chrome dev tools

Tags: vue.js, webpack, google-chrome-devtools

I try to setup the source maps in a hope it will cause to show a real position of an error in Chrome developer tools.

I tried these options in `vue.config.js`:

```
configureWebpack: {
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
},
```

and

```
configureWebpack: {
  devtool: 'source-map',
},
```

But I still get such error:

[image]

This is my `package.json` snippet

```
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
...
"devDependencies": {
  "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.12.1",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.12.1",
  "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
```

How to fix it? How does an error look with correctly set up the source map?

Update: Minimum reproducible project: https://wwww.github.com/literakl/vue-errors
It happens for the errors in vue components.

Comment: Please upvote: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10966

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are already using the VueJS devtool extension, but you should definitely use that in your overall workflow as well. Available for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/).

The reason I'm advising to use this is simply that sometimes your code might be correct, but as it is written in your error example "Cannot read property 'poll' of undefined" it looks like the prop poll is not being filled correctly by the parent component, or whatever is pushing data to the PollHeading.vue file.

With the Vue devtools you can inspect data, props and computed properties of a single component, watch events as they unfold and visually follow data streams throughout your application.

Escpecially with complex transfers of data this can get a little out of hand and a good tool to visualize this is a real life saver.

That said, getting explicit line numbers of an error in Vue2 is kind of a hit or miss situation; with Vue 2.5 and onward you're able to [place an errorHandler() hook](https://gist.github.com/yyx990803/9bdff05e5468a60ced06c29c39114c6b#error-handling-with-errorcaptured-hook) inside your component that will give you a detailed stacktrace. Try placing one in the PollHeading.vue file and see what output it'll give you. Should be much more detailed than the default output you got.

Answer (score 4):

The error should look something like this if the error occurs in the javascript part of the component: [image]

Looks like you have the correct settings, my `vue.config.js` looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

I also use `"@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.0"`

Make sure that you have restarted the serve-script -- it won't work otherwise

Comment: Would you be so kind and take a look at my repository? You may notice some difference. Thank you. https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/tree/master/spa

Comment: I tried to changed line 3 in your `vue.config.js` to `devtool: 'source-map',` restarted dev-server by running `npm run serve` again and then it worked, for transparency I added `this.asdf();` after line 54 in `App.vue` to induce an error. Hopefully that works. Added this in the last commit on https://github.com/perlindstroem/mezinamiridici forked from the repo you linked.

Comment: Your example error works for me as well. But when I have a bug is some component, there is no improvement. For example PollHeading:                 <li>{{itemz.poll.votes.total}} votes</li> (I added z after the item). It looks like in the screenshot in my question.

Comment: I have created minimum reproducibe project there: https://github.com/literakl/vue-errors

Answer (score 1):

Your error seems to be from the `template` part of the component.

Maps won't work on template errors as the template is converted to a big javascript function (render) and the connection between template and the render function is lost.

Your best is to set up an [error handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler) and log it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the error handler logs the same information I already had.